# Cutting contour lines over raster (building) areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, elevation, autocad

I am looking to cut the contours in ArcMap and /or AutoCAD so they don't pass through buildings or roads. Is there a process or code to do this, so it doesn't have to be done manually?

Also, looking to cut the contour lines so that they are able to display elevation labels with no lines running through them.

Comment: The labels should be handled with the labels by using a mask/halo, at least in Arc. I know that can be done in AutoCAD as well, but might require something like Civil to do (because the contours aren't just lines, they're an object). As far as cutting contours for buildings or roads, we need a bit more information. Is this for graphic purposes only, so you don't need actual break lines and the contours don't need to remain topologically correct? What format are the features in now (lines/polygons, shapefile/feature class)? Where does the raster come into play and does it have transparency?